# CodePen: having trouble formatting list text in a div [CSS]

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to style unordered list items in a div *'terminal style'*  but I can't get it  to work just right. 
 The list items are center aligned and bulleted instead of left aligned as I intend

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Oguntoye/pen/ZjeqQd)

CSS

```
.outputDiv ul{
   padding:0rem;
   margin:0rem;
}

.outputDiv li{
   list-style: none;
}
```

JS

```
  function processOutput(inputString = "", outputString) {
    const outputList = document.querySelector(".output-div ul");
    const listItem = document.createElement("li");
    const inputEl = document.createElement("kbd");
    const outputEl = document.createElement("samp");
    let echoInput = (inputEl.textContent = inputString);
    let scoobyspeak = (outputEl.textContent = outputString);

    const limitLines = (max = 0) => {
      if (outputList.childNodes.length === ++max)
        outputList.removeChild(outputList.childNodes[0]);
    };
    if (outputString === "") {
      listItem.innerHTML = "Please enter  some text into the input field";
      limitLines();
      outputList.appendChild(listItem);
    } else {
      listItem.innerHTML = `'${echoInput}' <i>scoobydized</i> to: <b>${scoobyspeak}</b>`;
      outputList.appendChild(listItem);
      limitLines(4);
    }
    initInput();
  }
```

Comment: in your codepen, your div wrapper is of class output-div, not outputDiv as in your css.

Comment: Aha!   Good  'ol fatigue induced human error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
.output-div ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px
}
```

You are referencing a different class name, and not using the correct selector.

*This one is tested on CodePen.*